# C# Optimize nested foreach loops

Tags: c#, linq

I've written an Library which works with a large excel and maps the entries into objects. But at some point it becomes really slow due to three nested foreach loops. I've seen some solutions with an dictionary but the problem there was a bit different as mine.

```
var house = new PostHouse();
house.FK_STRID = long.Parse(fields[2]);
if (!fields[3].Equals("")){
     house.HouseNumber = long.Parse(fields[3]);
}
foreach (var canton in cantons)
{
    foreach(var city in canton.Cities)
    {
        if (city.Streets == null) 
            city.Streets = new List<PostStreet>();
        foreach(var street in city.Streets)
        {
            if(street.STRID == house.FK_STRID)
            {
                if (street.Houses == null) 
                    street.Houses = new List<PostHouse>();
                street.Houses.Add(house);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It takes about 10 minute to loop over everything.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: loop performace: For loop is the best, if you cant use For loop, you could use foreach with local variable. (var lcantons = cantons and foreach(var canton in lcantons)

Comment: I take it that the foreach loop itself is not the problem. Reading from an xls file is the problem. Can you read it as a csv file?

Comment: At the very least you can extract `house.FK_STRID` into a local variable outside the loops. It probably won't help much, but it's worth doing.

Comment: It would take the entire country of Switzerland to make that last 10 minutes.  No simple dodges for too much data.  There's really only one thing you can do about it: do it just once and stuff it in a well-indexed database.  If you can't do it just once then focus on reading only changed data.  If you can't get that either then make sure that nobody is waiting for it.  Everybody is asleep at 3 o'clock in the morning :)

Comment: Where does `cantons` come from?

Comment: Did you use a profiler? Where exactly is the bottleneck?

Comment: Try to parallelize the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say because we don't know what type `cantons` and its children are and where they come from, but the main issue here is that you have a data structure that's not suited for the task. You have a hierarchical list of Streets inside Cities inside Cantons, when what you need is a list of Streets *indexed* by their STRID.

If you can do initial processing of how your streets are stored, you can do this:

```
var streetIndex = new Dictionary<string, PostStreet>();
foreach (var canton in cantons)
  foreach (var city in canton.Cities)
    foreach (var street in city.Streets)
    { 
        streetIndex.Add(street.STRID, street);
    }
```

then you can instantly look up a street by its STRID when you're iterating over houses in O(1) time.

```
foreach (var house in houses)
{
    if (streetIndex.ContainsKey(house.FK_STRID))
    {
       streetIndex[house.FK_STRID].Add(house);   
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not possible at this time, because i'm reading one line of the File and then i'm going to add it into the object. So preprocessing isn't working here..

Comment: @DominicJärmann If you're reading a file one line at a time then that's most likely where the speed issue is, read it in chunks (or if it's small, all at once)

Comment: This sounds like a job for deserialization. Re-using a library would be better, until you can improve that library.

Answer (score 0):

Do this stuff in your constructors or auto initliaize them

```
Streets = new List<PostStreet>();

...

Houses = new List<PostHouse>()
```

Then Linq

```
var streets = cantons.SelectMany(x => x.Cities)
                     .SelectMany(x => x.Streets)
                     .Where(x => x.STRID == house.FK_STRI);


foreach (var street in streets)
    street.Houses.Add(house);
```